# CakePHP getting data from multiple table

Tags: cakephp

Let's say I have 2 table.

One is floor, another is shop.

Inside floor table : 
id, floor_name

Inside shop table:
id, name, floor_id.

Meanwhile, the association is:
one floor hasMany shop, one shop hasOne floor.

ok , the question is ..

How  can I get the floor_name data directly while I'm only able to get the floor_id in my view ?

Example: I display all of the shop data as 
`$shop['Shop']['name'], $shop['Shop']['floor_id']`,
 which in my `/shops/main`

I want the `$shop['Shop']['floor_id']` field display the `$floor['Floor']['floor_name']` data ? possible ?

Comment: will u please add your find query here

Comment: There are many issues with this question including strange table naming conventions, incorrect (likely) associations, and referencing trying to get DB data from a view.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting belongsTo?

Answer (score 4):

Kampung,

You should have below mentioned association in you tables:

Floor hasMany Shops
Shop belongsTo Floor

Now in your controller when you will fetch data about your shop then you will get floor data automatically.

$shops=$this->Shop->read(null, $id);

Now $shops will contain two array
['Shop']=>array(.......)
['Floor']=>array(........)

so now to display the floor name, you need to use $shop['Floor']['floor_name'] instead of $floor['Floor']['floor_name']

Answer (score 1):

Define a `hasMany` Floor relationship in your Shop model. In your Floor model, define a `belongsTo`relationship to Shop. This will allow your associated data to be retrieved.

When retrieving your data via `$this->Shop->find('first', $arg)`, where `$arg` is your search option array, define the following

```
$arg['contains'] = array('Floor.name');
```

Now, you should get what you want.